# How to get the section character for names which start with a derived character

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, text-formatting

In android contacts application (or People app), a section is shown before contact names. e.g.

### A

a1
 a2

### B

b1
 b2

here A and B(shown in bold) are sections. and a1, a2, b1, b2 are contact names. how do they get the section character? for the above example it is simple because you may extract the first character using "a1".chatAt(0) in java code and then capitalize it. But consider the below example:

### A

a
 œ

### B

b1
 b2
in this example if you try to extract the first char in java using "œ".charAt(0), it will return you 'œ' and not 'a'. How can I get to know that 'a' is the base character for this?
Please note that I want to support all languages and similar issues will arise for those languages as well. Could somebody tell the solution which works for all languages.

Comment: Why are you classifying œ under A, not O? Were you perhaps thinking about æ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method that doesn't depend on the language.

Consider surname `Ölerman`:

- in English, you want to put it under **O**, between `Oldschool` and `Omsky`
- in German, you want to put it under **O**, between `Oderman` and `Offspring`
- in Swedish, you want to put it under **Ö**, at the very end of alphabet, after **XYZÅÄ**
- in Turkish, you want to put it under **Ö**, between **O** and **P**

So you need to pick an appropriate collation algorithm for user's language.

As for getting the "first letter", I think this may be a good start:

```
// I recommend using ICU4J for collation instead
Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(userLocale);
char result = Character.toUppercase(name.charAt(0));
String key = name.charAt(0) + "a";

for(char c = 'A', c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    String cs = Character.toString(c);
    if(coll.compare(cs, key)<0 && coll.compare(key,cs+"z")<0){
        result = c;
        break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to sort the "first letters" and the names under each letter using the same collator.

Comment: +1 for `userLocale` as it indeed depends *only* on The Current User's Locale.